# Is it possible to test scroll events in qUnit?

Tags: jquery, qunit

I'm using `window.scrollTo(0,400)` but qUnit seems to be calling `window.scrollTo(0,0)` all the time preventing the scroll of the page. Therefore I can not test the behaviour of my application when scrolling.

What's the way to go for it?

Comment: I would create a wrapper around the `window` object that exposes its own `scrollTo()` function, which calls `window.scrollTo()`, and then test that your code calls your wrapper class and calls it with the correct values.